# How to start using Apache solr with Java and run simple queries without running into errors?

Tags: java, solr

I have been trying to run and try Apache solr (connecting and running Java queries) in Windows for two days, and it took me about 15 different stackoverflow searches and 5 long tutorials to overcome all the errors and questions that I was facing. This question is intended as a self-Q&A for those experiencing the same problems. I'm using: Windows 7, Apache solr 5.5.0, Maven and Eclipse. Note: I know I'm not covering absolutely everything, but I hope I can help people overcome some of their problems!

Questions that will be (hopefully) covered:

1. Where do I download solr? (SO independent)
2. How do I start solr (from the windows console)?
3. How do I create a collection (from the windows console)?
4. How do I create a connection from Java? (SO independent)
5. How do I add a document to my collection? (SO independent)
6. How do I delete a document from my collection? (SO independent)
7. How do I query my documents? (SO independent)
8. Can I access my collection from the browser and how?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Where do I download solr? (SO independent)

   You can get solr 5.5.0 from [here](http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.lua/lucene/solr/5.5.0).
2. How do I start solr (from the windows console)?

   ```
   $ solr-5.5.0/bin/solr.cmd start
   ```
3. How do I create a collection (from the windows console)?

   ```
   $ solr-5.5.0/bin/solr create -c gettingstarted
   ```

   where "gettingstarted" is the name of your collection.
4. How do I create a connection from Java? (SO independent)

   This part is a bit tricky, since it has changed over different solr releases. Right now, you can do it like this:

   ```
   String urlString = "http://localhost:8983/solr/gettingstarted";
   SolrClient solr = new HttpSolrClient(urlString);
   ```

   Notice that the url doesn't contain "#/~cores". It will give you connection errors if you copy the full url like that.
5. How do I add a document to my collection? (SO independent)

   ```
   // Adds a document containing two fields: id and first_name, with
   // values "123" and "randombee" respectively
   SolrInputDocument document = new SolrInputDocument();
   document.addField("id", "123");
   document.addField("first_name", "randombee");
   solr.add(document);
   solr.commit(); // you MUST do this to commit the changes to your collection
   ```
6. How do I delete a document from my collection? (SO independent)

   There are two different ways you can do this: deleting a document by id (if you already know that field) or deleting a document by query.

   ```
   // Deletes document with id="mymockid"
   solr.deleteById("mymockid");
   solr.commit();

   // Deletes all documents with first_name:randombee
   solr.deleteByQuery("first_name:randombee");
   solr.commit();
   ```
7. How do I query my documents? (SO independent)

   Two examples on how to do it. If you want to query all the documents in the collection, you can use *:* in your query to achieve it:

   ```
   // Queries all documents (*:*) and shows only the id
   SolrQuery query = new SolrQuery();
   query.setQuery("*:*"); // actual query
   QueryResponse response = null;
   try {
       response = solr.query(query);
   } catch (SolrServerException e) {/* */ }
   SolrDocumentList list = response.getResults();
   System.out.println(list.toString()); // print the results of the query
   ```

   Query for specific data:

   ```
   // Queries documents with first_name=randombee or id=SP2514N
   // and shows fields id and name
   query = new SolrQuery();
   query.setQuery("first_name:randombee OR id:SP2514N");
   query.setFields("id", "name"); // set fields you want to show

   response = null;
   try {
       response = solr.query(query);
   } catch (SolrServerException e) {/* */ }
   list = response.getResults();
   System.out.println(list.toString());
   ```

   which gives me this result:

   {numFound=1,start=0,docs=[SolrDocument{id=123, first_name=randombee}]}
8. Can I access my collection from the browser?

   Assuming solr is running in localhost and port 8983, accessing http://localhost:8983/solr/mycollection/browse will show you all the documents in the collection "mycollection". Note that the path **is not** http://localhost:8983/solr/#/~cores/gettingstarted, even if that is the path showing when you access all the cores. You have to remove the #/~cores part and add the /browse to see your collection.

Comment: Good job on the Q&A, but you might want to change your formatting a bit to make the paragraphs more clear (at the moment the separators (1. ..., 2. ...) are indented, and not the actual content of the paragraphs (which might be due to the formatting of a different text editor)).

Comment: Thanks for the tip @Seth, I didn't know how to do it, but it looks ok now :)